# Default popViewController transition fading unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Im my application the default `popViewController` transition is not working -- it shows a fade in transition instead.

Push animation is animating as expected but pop animation isn't. I'm simply using

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

for popping the viewController.

Any idea why its behaving like this?

Comment: Post some code, otherwise there is very little to go

Comment: post the code to get help

Comment: The thing is i have no idea why its behaving like this, push animation is working fine but pop animation is not working. Im simply using [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; for poping the viewController

Comment: When you say "not working" what do you mean?

Comment: I mean it shows FadeIn transition insted of default pop transition

Comment: @Ahmad Did you use a fade transition at any other point in your app?

Comment: @LyndseyScott i have used Fade animation at few places, for example im hiding my activityIndicater with fade effect,

Answer (score 0):

If you've used a fade animation to perform a transition at any other point in your view, you'll have to remove that animation from your view's layer, ex:

```
[self.navigationController.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Its not working for me, for issue you can see the gif https://imgflip.com/gif/gxbre

Comment: @Ahmad looking at your animation, it's not fading... If you look at the nav bar, it actually looks like the animation is sliding just like the default pop animation. It looks like possibly your app's memory is being overworked during that transition though and causing it to glitch

Comment: in Debug navigator it shows my application is using 18.5MB memory, if my memory is overloading why push animation working fine?

Comment: @Ahmad Animations can be affected when your app is devoting excessive memory to other processes or when another animation conflicts with that original animation... What happens upon popping your view? For example, if your viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear?